# Fck Editor Multiple Editors

Tags: javascript, html, editor, textarea, fckeditor

How would I be able to achieve something like this: have multiple textareas and only want one toolbar. What I want: 
`<div id="Editor">`
`<!-- Toolbar will go here -->`

`</div>`
`<textarea>Some content...</textarea>`
`<textarea>Some content...</textarea>`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the /_samples/html/sample10.html file as that's just that example.